# Hadoop 3.1.1 for windows

Tags: hadoop

> This change updates the Microsoft Windows build directions to be more flexible with regards to Visual Studio compiler versions:
>
> Any version of Visual Studio 2010 Pro or higher may be used.
> http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/release/3.1.1/RELEASENOTES.3.1.1.html

any clue how to build hadoop using VS2015?

Comment: Why do you need to build it exactly? Have you read the build instructions?

Comment: Because this is the way to install hadoop over windows

Comment: No it isn't? Hadoop is just a Java process you download like any other. Only the native libraries need compiled, and it'll work without them